# How to factor $56x^4+18x^2-8$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I've been trying to figure out how you solve this question but I just can't seem to understand how to factor

$$56x^4+18x^2-8$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As others have hinted at, start by letting $t=x^2$. Then you get the following:
$$
56x^4+18x^2-8 = 56t^2+18t-8.
$$
Now your job is to factor this:
\begin{align}
56t^2+18t-8 &= 2(4t-1)(7t+4)\\[0.5em]
            &= 2(4x^2-1)(7x^2+4)\\[0.5em]
            &= 2(2x-1)(2x+1)(7x^2+4).
\end{align}
Thus, we see that
$$
56x^4+18x^2-8 = 2(2x-1)(2x+1)(7x^2+4).
$$

Comment: Nice substitution and answer!

Comment: That was a very poor approved edit @Shailesh & Leucippus.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is: Set $t=x^2$. So you have

$56t^2+18t-8=2(28t^2+9t-4)$

$\Delta=9^2+4\cdot28\cdot4=81+448=529$

$t_{1,2}=\frac{-9\pm \sqrt{529}}{56}=\frac{-9\pm 23}{56}$

$t_1=-\frac{32}{56}=-\frac{4}{7}$ $t_2=\frac{14}{56}=\frac{1}{4}$

so

$56(t-\frac{1}{4})(t+\frac{4}{7})$

$56(x^2-\frac{1}{4})(x^2+\frac{4}{7})=$

$56(x-\frac{1}{2})(x+\frac{1}{2})(x^2+\frac{4}{7})=$

$2(2x+1)(2x-1)(7x^2+4)$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $y = x^2$ and then factor.

Comment: It's a factoring question, what you're given is what you solve for, there is no Y therefore I cannot factor for Y.

Comment: @Dunja Aaron/lhf are telling you to notice that you can solve $56(x^2)^2+18x^2-8$ for the value of $x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Set $u=x^2$. Factor the resulting quadratic in $u$.

Comment: (and then factor each of the pieces in $x$)